# How to complete this specific question/query using SQL and an inline view?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently working on a hotel project where I need to make queries with SQL but I'm stuck on one question.

The question is:

How many employees have made at least 2 bookings for at least 3 customers?

I have figured out that I need to use an inline view but I have not gone any further because I'm stuck on the next part.

This is the table in the database:

```
bookingid    | int | primary key    
bookingdate  | date| -   
numOfGuests  | int | -
customerId   | int | foreign key 
employeeId   | int | foreign key


 bookingid | bookingdate | numOfGuests | customerId | employeeId
     1       2016-01-25        4            2             2
     2       2016-06-12        1            3             2
     3       2016-12-05        1            2             2
     4       2016-04-01        2            3             2
     5       2016-11-01        3            2             3
     6       2016-11-03        1            8             2
     7       2017-06-02        6            2             2
     8       2016-02-07        2            8             2
     9       2016-12-25        2            4             5
     10      2017-06-21        1            10            2
     11      2016-08-12        2            10            2
     ...         ...          ...          ...           ...
```

So does anyone know how to complete this question with a SQL query using an inline view?

The result I want are the employeeId's or id that satisfies the specifications of the question: Result based on sample data

```
CountOfemployeeID |   
        1
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  A db fiddle would also help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added the things you asked for! :)

Comment: please also add your desired output from the result set.

Comment: @mkRabbani Done! :)

Comment: The result MUST be based on the sample data

Comment: @DanielBrughera On it!

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I hope the question is clear now

Comment: `having count(distinct customerId) >= 3 ...`

Comment: @jarlh but then I'm not using an inline view right?

Comment: That's a part of the derived table!

Comment: @jarlh So how do I need to see that in the whole query?

Comment: @portalstudent see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this script-

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT C.employeeId)
FROM
(
    SELECT A.employeeId,B.customerid,COUNT(B.bookingid) T
    FROM (
        --Select users who atlease booked for 3 customer
        SELECT employeeId,COUNT(DISTINCT customerid) customerid
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY employeeId
        HAVING COUNT(customerid)> 2
    )A
    --Select users who atleast booked twice per customer
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT bookingid,bookingdate,numOfGuests,customerId,employeeId
        FROM Table1
    ) B
    ON A.employeeId = B.employeeId
    GROUP BY A.employeeId,B.customerid
    HAVING COUNT(B.bookingid) > 1
)C
```

Comment: This one works! Thanks! But I have one question. Is it necessary to do the whole join? Is section A not enough?

Comment: Section A is not enough as you required 2 level checking. 1st, a employee must booked for 3 customer and 2nd is, he must need to book at least twice from each customer. This two filtering can not be perform with one go.

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @userData TABLE(
bookingid int,
bookingdate date,   
numOfGuests int,
customerId int,
employeeId int
)

insert into @userData
values
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 2, 2),
    (2, '2016-06-12', 1, 3, 3),
    (3, '2016-12-05', 1, 2, 4),
    (4, '2016-04-01', 2, 2, 3),
    (5, '2016-11-12', 3, 2, 3),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 5, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 5, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 5, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 5, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 5, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 5, 5),
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 2, 2),
    (2, '2016-06-12', 1, 3, 3),
    (3, '2016-12-05', 1, 2, 4),
    (4, '2016-04-01', 2, 2, 3),
    (5, '2016-11-12', 3, 2, 3),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 2, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 2, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 3, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 3, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 4, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 4, 5),
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 2, 2),
    (2, '2016-06-12', 1, 3, 3),
    (3, '2016-12-05', 1, 2, 4),
    (4, '2016-04-01', 2, 2, 3),
    (5, '2016-11-12', 3, 2, 3),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 1, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 2, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 3, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 4, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 7, 5),
    (6, '2017-01-15', 1, 6, 5),
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 3, 2),
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 3, 2),
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 1, 2),
    (1, '2016-01-25', 4, 1, 2)

    select * from @userData

    ; with CTE as
    (
        select count(customerId) count, customerId, employeeId from @userData
        group by customerId, employeeid having count(customerid) >= 2
    ), cte2 as 
    (
        Select employeeId from CTE group by Employeeid having count(employeeId) >= 3
    )
    select count, customerid, employeeid from CTE as a
    inner join CTE2 as b on a.employeeId = b.employeeId
```

OUTPUT

```
count customerId    employeeId
    2   1   2
    3   2   2
    2   3   2
    3   2   5
    3   3   5
    3   4   5
    6   5   5
```

If You need only the  EmployeeId, then just fire

```
Select employeeId from CTE2
```

output

```
Employeeid
2
5
```

Comment: This one is working and correct! I'm sorry for asking but what is an CTE. Is there another easier way to do get this result? Inline view?

Comment: @portalstudent CTE is common table expression. Mark as Answer if it satisfy your conditions

Comment: I guess it does answer my question so I mark it. But the thing is I don't realy understand what you are doing.

Comment: @portalstudent i am just using CTE, it allows recurrsive query on same dataset

Comment: Here i write a query CTE and reused the output in cte2 and then again used CTE and CTE2 for the output